# how to use kapt in androidTest scope

Tags: android, annotations, kotlin, apt, kapt

Is there a way to use kapt for the androidtest scope? Currently I am migrating from com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins android-apt to kapt - which works fine - but I am not sure how to do it for the androidTest scope - so replacing:

```
apt "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:$permissiondispatcher_version"
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
```

with

```
kapt "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:$permissiondispatcher_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
```

works fine - but I found no way to migrate:

```
androidTestApt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#annotation-processing), it's `kaptAndroidTest` (and `kaptTest` for unit tests).